# SVN Showing question Mark(?) With each file in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn

In eclipse Kepler i have took the project from SVN and when i am doing Right Click on `Project->Team->Sychronised With repository` it is showing 10000 changes while few hour back i took the whole project from svn, but still it is showing `?` with all the files .

Can any one tell what is the issue and how can i resolve it?

One more thing i have to add in eclipse my project look like `projectName[/trunk/workspace/projectname]` it mean my project well connected with SVN.

Even i Have done `Team->Update to Head` and `Team->Update to Version` but no any success.

Answer (score 0):

From `trunk/workspace/projectname`, it looks like you have added your workspace in trunk. Check whether this is correct.

Comment: Evertthing is fine..it is something like somename/trunk/workspace/projectName

Answer (score 0):

'?' indicates new source and '*' indicates a modified file.  Did you by chance change the directory structure after you checked out?  That would definitely mess up the .svn files.  All move operations should be done within the IDE - even then it still messes up.

Comment: I did not get success so i just disconnect the svn and reconnect it